# Wireless not working after clean install on of ubuntu 14.04 on Dell 1501

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, dell, broadcom

I have installed Ubuntu for the first time and it looks great. I got the wired Internet to work using instructions from other threads but I can't get the wireless to work.

Please see output from terminal screen below. Your help is greatly appreciated

```
oliverd@oliverd-Inspiron-1501:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
joydev                 17381  0 
dm_crypt               23177  0 
dell_wmi               12761  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 dell_wmi
snd_hda_codec_idt      54645  1 
dell_laptop            18168  0 
dcdbas                 14928  1 dell_laptop
snd_hda_intel          52355  3 
snd_hda_codec         192906  2 snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102099  2 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
kvm_amd                59987  0 
b43                   387371  0 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
kvm                   451511  1 kvm_amd
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
bcma                   52096  1 b43
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
mac80211              626489  1 b43
psmouse               102222  0 
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
edac_core              62291  0 
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
serio_raw              13462  0 
k8temp                 12978  0 
edac_mce_amd           22617  0 
sp5100_tco             13979  0 
snd                    69238  16 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
cfg80211              484040  2 b43,mac80211
soundcore              12680  1 snd
i2c_piix4              22155  0 
ssb_hcd                12869  0 
rfcomm                 69160  0 
bnep                   19624  2 
shpchp                 37032  0 
bluetooth             395423  10 bnep,rfcomm
parport_pc             32701  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
mac_hid                13205  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
pata_acpi              13038  0 
b44                    40234  0 
sdhci_pci              23172  0 
radeon               1514165  3 
sdhci                  43015  1 sdhci_pci
mii                    13934  1 b44
pata_atiixp            13271  0 
video                  19476  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 radeon
ttm                    85115  1 radeon
wmi                    19177  1 dell_wmi
drm_kms_helper         52758  1 radeon
drm                   302817  5 ttm,drm_kms_helper,radeon
ssb                    62379  3 b43,b44,ssb_hcd
ahci                   25819  2 
libahci                32168  1 ahci
oliverd@oliverd-Inspiron-1501:~$ dmesg | grep b4
[    1.540144] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.540149] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.540152] usb usb4: Product: OHCI PCI host controller
[    1.540156] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-24-generic ohci_hcd
[    1.540160] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:13.2
[    1.775892] Freeing unused kernel memory: 708K (ffff880001b4f000 - ffff880001c00000)
[    2.056503] b44: Broadcom 44xx/47xx 10/100 PCI ethernet driver version 2.0
[    2.077277] b44 ssb1:0 eth0: Broadcom 44xx/47xx 10/100 PCI ethernet driver 00:19:b9:62:59:aa
[    5.672719] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4311 WLAN found (core revision 10)
[    5.719298] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 4, Type 2 (G), Revision 8
[    5.740934] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[    5.740944] b43 ssb0:0: Falling back to user helper
[    6.673348] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[    6.673358] b43 ssb0:0: Falling back to user helper
[    6.812120] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[    6.812129] b43 ssb0:0: Falling back to user helper
[    6.819769] b43 ssb0:0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[    6.819777] b43 ssb0:0: Falling back to user helper
[    6.827963] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode5.fw" not found
[    6.827971] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode5.fw" not found
[    6.827976] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
[   55.516262] b44 ssb1:0 eth0: powering down PHY
[   57.212702] Modules linked in: joydev dm_crypt dell_wmi sparse_keymap snd_hda_codec_idt dell_laptop dcdbas snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_page_alloc kvm_amd b43 snd_seq_midi kvm snd_seq_midi_event bcma snd_rawmidi snd_seq mac80211 psmouse snd_seq_device edac_core snd_timer serio_raw k8temp edac_mce_amd sp5100_tco snd cfg80211 soundcore i2c_piix4 ssb_hcd rfcomm bnep shpchp bluetooth parport_pc ppdev lp mac_hid parport pata_acpi b44 sdhci_pci radeon sdhci mii pata_atiixp video i2c_algo_bit ttm wmi drm_kms_helper drm ssb ahci libahci
[   57.212779]  [<ffffffff810b40a5>] suspend_devices_and_enter+0x315/0x440
[   57.212782]  [<ffffffff810b4348>] pm_suspend+0x178/0x260
[   57.212796]  [<ffffffff811b9534>] vfs_write+0xb4/0x1f0
[   61.920111] Corrupted low memory at ffff880000007bd8 (7bd8 phys) = 20107c00e5cb4839
[   61.920157] Modules linked in: joydev dm_crypt dell_wmi sparse_keymap snd_hda_codec_idt dell_laptop dcdbas snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_page_alloc kvm_amd b43 snd_seq_midi kvm snd_seq_midi_event bcma snd_rawmidi snd_seq mac80211 psmouse snd_seq_device edac_core snd_timer serio_raw k8temp edac_mce_amd sp5100_tco snd cfg80211 soundcore i2c_piix4 ssb_hcd rfcomm bnep shpchp bluetooth parport_pc ppdev lp mac_hid parport pata_acpi b44 sdhci_pci radeon sdhci mii pata_atiixp video i2c_algo_bit ttm wmi drm_kms_helper drm ssb ahci libahci
oliverd@oliverd-Inspiron-1501:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:b9:62:59:aa  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:21 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2528 (2.5 KB)  TX bytes:2528 (2.5 KB)
```

Comment: ifconfig doesn't show wlan0 present.  What kind of wireless card you have ?

Comment: Nevermind, I see in dmesg it reports b43 card. Have you looked at [this article ?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)

Answer (score 0):

Since Ubuntu is loading the b43 driver there is only one possibility for your card
You need the firmware for the card, `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` and reboot

If it doesn't work check `rfkill list all` for any hard or soft blocks, if none are found

I doubt your computer will use bcmwl-kernel-source as installing it will blacklist your ethernet driver- b44

Comment: sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer + reboot worked, thanks a million!